# Save bookmarklets in GMarks?

Tags: google-bookmarks

How can I save a bookmarklet (a javascript bookmark, like "Gmail this"..) in Gmarks?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See [this blog post](http://jus.tumblr.com/post/111169437/getting-bookmarklets-to-work-with-gmarks-and-google).

> into the URL field. Now, push ‘Home’
>   and simply add a whitespace at the
>   beginning of the URL field, i.e. right
>   before “javascript”. That’s it. Accept
>   the bookmark. And try it out.